# On meta sites, show the badges progress only when the user can edit posts

Tags: feature-request, review, per-site-meta

On the review site for the meta site for *Ask Different*, the review page shows me the following block:

[image: screenshot]

As my reputation on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/3598/kiamlaluno) only allows me to suggest edits, and on a meta site it is not possible to suggest edits, that information should not be visible to me. It should be shown only when the users can edit posts on the meta site.

Comment: What is "ask different"?  *Edit*:  Oh... [apple.SE] - I should have known.